# Expo-ios / facebook login doesn't work standalone app

Tags: ios, expo, react-native-ios

I've recently finished programming an app I've created using react native and expo. I used expo simulator to test the app on both ios and android and they both seem to work, but when I created the ipa file using `expo build:ios` and ran it with testFlight, the facebook login didn't work (pressing the login button doesn't do anything).

I'm using `Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync` function to log-in.

Answer (score 0):

A fix - updateds RN SDK to v32.0.0

Answer (score 0):

> If you ask question with the code section, it will be helpful.

Add **behavior: 'web'** as below.

It worked for me in Expo client and production as well.

```
Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(Config.loginSetup.facebookID, 
 { 
 permissions: ['public_profile','email'],
 behavior: 'web'
 })
```